# findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.5 Failure

Tags: maven, jenkins, findbugs

I am running a job in Jenkins. Something unusual is happening since last few days. When I am. running the same job, sometimes it succeeds & sometimes it fails.

Success Message

```
12:01:43 [INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.5:findbugs (default-cli)
12:01:44 [INFO] Fork Value is true
12:04:24      [java] Warnings generated: 1556
12:04:24 [INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
```

Failure Message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.5:findbugs (default-cli) on project
```

Can someone please tell me the reason for such an erratic behavior?

Comment: I suppose there is much more in the log output...which JDK version are you running?

Comment: @khmarbaise its jdk_1.8.0_171